# Deleting top rows only. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I delete only the top row of a table in SQL Server?

I did:

```
set rowcount 1;
delete * from table;
set rowcount 0;
```

But I am not sure if its a good way to do it.

Is there any better way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE: oops!  @gbn is right, my ORDER BY sample was broken! Updating with correct code sample.**

In the most common case where the "top" is based the order of values in a particular column or columns, you can use a CTE and ROW_NUMBER to simulate an ordered TOP:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeColumn, OtherColumn) AS RowNum
  FROM table
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RowNum <= 1;
```

See [Itzik Ben-Gan's SQLMag article on TOP](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/49240/sql_server_49240.html) for more info on this suggested pattern.

If you simply want to delete any row of a set of duplicates, or just want to delete a random row for some reason, then it's safe to omit the ORDER BY and do something simpler:

`DELETE TOP (1) FROM table`

Quoting from the [DELETE docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

> TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] 
>   Specifies the number or percent of
>   random rows that will be deleted.
>   expression can be either a number or a
>   percent of the rows. The rows
>   referenced in the TOP expression used
>   with INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE are not
>   arranged in any order.
>
> Parentheses delimiting expression in
>   TOP are required in INSERT, UPDATE,
>   and DELETE statements. For more
>   information, see [TOP (Transact-SQL).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Comment: doh! I tested out the unordered version first and then my 6-month-old started crying and I got called away for baby duty before I finished testing the ORDER BY variant. :-)  Meant to get back to it last night but didn't make it back until now.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4):

- TOP is meaningless without ORDER BY
- Use WITH TIES to deal with joint top
- You can't use ORDER BY directly in a DELETE so you have to workaround it

Like this:

```
DELETE foo
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 /*WITH TIES*/ * FROM Mytable ORDER BY WhatDecidesTop) foo;

;WITH Foo AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 /*WITH TIES*/ * FROM Mytable ORDER BY WhatDecidesTop
)
DELETE foo;
```

Comment: +1 for shorter (and more correct!) answer than mine, and for suggesting WITH TIES.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that it will delete *one* row at random, you need to be more specific (such as using an order by clause) to make sure you are deleting what you want. Better yet - add a where clause with the primary key for the row you really want to delete and drop the "rowcount" clause altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim mySqlCommondDelete As String = "DELETE BOOK_ID,MemberID FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ISSUE_BOOK) where BOOK_ID = Val(" & deleteBook & ") and MemberID = Val(" & msk & ")"
```

this is work for ms access sql.i tested...only one first raw deleted...

only first row will be delete

Comment: I don't think your answer is sql. Looks more like VB to me.